# django urlib2 call

Tags: python, django, urllib2

I am trying to call urllib2 simple code.

```
import urllib2
f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
print f.read(100)
```

m getting this error

```
File "urllib.py", line 13, in <module>
    import urllib2
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 111, in <module>
    from urllib import (unwrap, unquote, splittype, splithost, quote,
  File "/home/vclub/vclubdev/vclubcms/urllib.py", line 14, in <module>
    f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'
```

Please suggest what i need to do for solving this error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a file called `urllib.py` in your working directory. It's confusing Python's `import` mechanism.

You should rename it.